# How to check if a column vector has logical 1 elements?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I want to check if a column vector has logical 1s.
Say, `A = [0;0;0;0;1;0;1;0;0;0]`,

```
    if (any element in A is a logical 1)
           "perform an operation"
    end
```

What should I use as a conditional statement? I would prefer using  vectorized code if possible.

Comment: @aioobe that works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Matlab array can only have one type. You cannot have a double and a logical in the same array. You can either use `sum(A) > 0` as a condition, as @aioobe suggested (preferrably, if you know that they are nonnegative), or you can use `any(A)` as a condition.

Comment: yes there will be only 0s and 1s elements in the column vector.

Comment: I think `any(A)` is still preferable, because it matches the context better, also it may be faster.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `any`. `any` is clearly the best choice here.

Comment: I tried using any(A) but it returns a True only if the entire column vector elements are 1.

Comment: Please read the doc for any. It will give false, if and only if all entries of its argument are 0 or false.

Comment: Oh I get it, I was using any(A)==1 and that is why it was returning a True only when all the elements were 1. But any(1) works absolutely perfect. Spent so much hours on this. Thanks a lot @Wauzl